# Store timestamp and their price values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql table "auctions". The "quantity available", "price" and the "current timestamp" will be updated every hour from an extern API.

```
item_id | item_class | item_subclass  | quantity vailable  | price | current timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |            |                |                    |       |
```

I want to store these datas for a price/ quantity archive. For that I need to archivate the older datas (quantity available, price and their timestamps- the "item_id" should be the access column).
I think I need to create another table but I don´t know whats the best way to structure it, since it need to be updated every hour with old datas.

-> Whats the best way to safe timestamps and their respective values (like the price), so they don´t get updated every hour.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whats the best way to safe timestamps and their respective values, so they don´t get updated every hour.

Comment: You can attach triggers to the table to help save the data in another table ON-INSERT ... you can call the new table history or log. Here is something to get you started.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx/

Comment: This sounds good. But whats the different to a cronjob which executes the "insert" every hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating this table with the 'item_id' as the primary key, you need to create another table with one more column say backup_id (this will be the primary key for the second table). After every hour when you are going to "update" mysql table 'auctions', "insert" the same entry in the second table.

Comment: Thanks. If it´s another table can´t I use the item_id as the primaray key? Or why do I need a backup id?

Comment: As primary key holds a unique value, If you use item_id as the primary key, it will get only one set of timestamp with respective values. Instead in the second table if you use another primary key (e.g. backup_id), backup_id will have unique values (You can set an auto increment for that), but item_id is free to have diffrent rows with same values. Therefore number of pairs of timestamp and respective values will be stored for same item_id.